# Pushing elements into array leads to modification of the previous elements

Tags: javascript

I am pushing elements into array, and the problem is that each time I push a new element, all the previous elements become equal to the last one.
I have come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932584/array-push-makes-all-elements-the-same-when-pushing-an-object), but I still can't see how to fix the issue

Please see this jsFiddle. As the post suggests, I moved the declaration of `instance` to the for-loop, but I've still got the same problem. Namely, the output of the code looks like this: `[46, 46]`. However, I would expect it to be `[23, 46]`.

I am really going crazy. Any ideas???

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = {'name': 'Anna', 'counter': 1}
  var counters = [23, 46];
  var result = [];
  $(counters).each(function() {
    
      var instance = json;
      instance.counter = this;
      result.push(instance);
  });
  
  $(result).each(function(){
      $('#test').append('<li>' + this.counter + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = 'test'>

</ul>
```

Comment: you have the same object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do deep copy using `var instance = jQuery.extend(true,{},json);`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = {'name': 'Anna', 'counter': 1}
  var counters = [23, 46];
  var result = [];
  $(counters).each(function() {
    
      var instance = jQuery.extend(true,{},json);
      instance.counter = this;
      result.push(instance);
  });
  
  $(result).each(function(){
      $('#test').append('<li>' + this.counter + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = 'test'>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the object inside of the `each` function and create for every call a new reference, without using the same reference to the object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counters = [23, 46];
  var result = [];
  $(counters).each(function() {
      var instance = { name: 'Anna', counter: 1 };
      instance.counter = this;
      result.push(instance);
  });
  
  $(result).each(function(){
      $('#test').append('<li>' + this.counter + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = 'test'></ul>
```

As alternative, you could create a new object with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = {'name': 'Anna', 'counter': 1}
  var counters = [23, 46];
  var result = [];
  $(counters).each(function() {
      var instance = Object.create(json);
      instance.counter = this;
      result.push(instance);
  });
  
  $(result).each(function(){
      $('#test').append('<li>' + this.counter + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = 'test'></ul>
```