# Array of objects contains same object over and over again

Tags: javascript

I create multiple objects and push them to the array `objArr`:

```js
var objArr = [];
var obj = {};
var height = [9,8,7,3,6,5,2,4];

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
debugger;
  var mountainH = height[i];

  obj.h = mountainH;
  obj.index = i;

  objArr.push(obj);
}

for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {

  alert(objArr[i].h);
}
```

But as you can see, each object has the same values. Why?

[image]

Comment: Because you aren't creating a bunch of objects, just modifying the same one over and over.

Comment: Because you're reusing the same `obj` on each push. So each time you mutate it by doing `obj.h = ...` it will change all the previously pushed ones too. Try creating the object inside the loop instead.

Comment: The value updates are by reference.

Comment: You shouldn't use a for loop with a static number like that. If you array changes, you have to modify it. use `height.length` to avoid nonsensical issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() makes all elements the same when pushing an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932584/array-push-makes-all-elements-the-same-when-pushing-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the scope of `obj` in your code is global and it should rather be contained in the for loop.

If you will not declare it inside the loop then the value will get overwritten of the same `obj` on each iteration instead of a new memory allocation.

```js
var objArr = [];
var height = [9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 5, 2, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  debugger;
  var mountainH = height[i];
  var obj = {};

  obj.h = mountainH;
  obj.index = i;

  objArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

- Put the initialization of `obj` within your `for-loop`.

You were re-assigning new values to a global variable `obj`.

```js
var objArr = [];

var height = [9,8,7,3,6,5,2,4];

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
debugger;
  var obj = {};
  var mountainH = height[i];

  obj.h = mountainH;
  obj.index = i;

  objArr.push(obj);
}

for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {

  console.log(objArr[i].h);
}
```

Comment: I even tried this before on jsfiddle, but then the whole site freezed.

Comment: @Black that's weird.  Probably you had a further logic.

Comment: you are probably right, it was probably other code which comes after it which causes the freeze

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you need to initialize a new object in each iteration of the loop, otherwise all your array members simply share the same object *reference*.

Additionally, your code can be greatly reduced by building the array using `.map()`, and fully using the object literal initializer to declare the properties.

```js
var height = [9,8,7,3,6,5,2,4];
var objArr = height.map((n, i) => ({h: n, index: i}));

console.log(objArr);
```

This is shorter and clearer. For every number in `height`, it creates a new object and adds it to a new array, which is returned from `.map()`.

---

It can be even a little shorter with the newer features for object literals.

```js
var height = [9,8,7,3,6,5,2,4];
var objArr = height.map((h, index) => ({h, index}));

console.log(objArr);
```