# How can i put data to Array by using javascript forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

with the below code my expected result is

```
[{'log1': 'v1'}, {'log2': 'v2'}, {'log3': 'v3'}]
```

```js
let testArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let logArray = [{
  'log1': 'v1'
}, {
  'log2': 'v2'
}, {
  'log3': 'v3'
}]

function arrayTest() {
  let ret = []
  let temp
  testArray.forEach(function(value, outIdx) {
    logArray.forEach(function(value, inIdx) {
      temp = value
    })
    ret.push(temp) // how can i capture the value of "logArray.forEach" to push "ret" array?
  })

  console.log(ret)
}
```

but this code shows the below result.

```
[ { log3: 'v3' }, { log3: 'v3' }, { log3: 'v3' } ]
```

How can i get my expected result?

Comment: Why not just `result = logArray` ?

Comment: if the two arrays have always the same length you can use : ret.push(logArray[outIdx])

Comment: @JonasW. this is short-handed code. actually outer array(testArray) will be used inner array(logArray) to add some testArray's value to logArray.

Comment: i got an answer from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932584/array-push-makes-all-elements-the-same-when-pushing-an-object?noredirect=1&lq=1