# Object gets always last value in forEach loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Trying to filter the results in `array2` based on the value `type` of `array1` but the resultant array always prints the last value in the forEach loop.

**Snippet**

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: "Audi",
    type: "sedan"
  },
  {
    name: "BMW",
    type: "sedan"
  },
  {
    name: "Benz",
    type: "suv"
  }
];
const array2 = [{
  year: "2020"
}, {
  year: "2021"
}];

let a = [];
let customObject1 = {};
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach((val1) => {
  array2.forEach((val2) => {
    if (val1.type === "sedan") {
      customObject1["label"] = "Sedan Car";
      customObject1["year"] = val2.year;
      array3.push(customObject1);
      console.log(array3);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the result that I'm expecting. Could anyone please help?

```
array3 = [{label: 'Sedan Car', year: '2020'}, {label: 'Sedan Car', year: '2021'}]
```

Comment: I absolutely cannot see how the two datasets relate to each other - You're trying to get a weird result based on what logic exactly? *"Trying to filter the results in array2"* filter what?

Comment: Would C# duplicate work? The same "not creating object on each iteration"... Surprising that there is no such easily searchable one in JavaScript. My mistake - to add to array in JavaScript you push it out :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.push() makes all elements the same when pushing an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932584/array-push-makes-all-elements-the-same-when-pushing-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the customObject1 each loop when you push to array3, you can use JSON.stringify() and then JSON.parse() to get a copy of that object (with a new reference in memory), otherwise you are overwriting the reference of the same object each loop. Check this to understand how JS handle objects in memory: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0.

```js
let a = [];
let customObject1 = {};
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach((val1) => {
  array2.forEach((val2) => {
    if (val1.type === "sedan") {
      customObject1["label"] = "Sedan Car";
      customObject1["year"] = val2.year;
      array3.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(customObject1)));
      console.log(array3);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: seems like a overhead to create a deep copy every inner iteration instead of creating a new inner scoped variable

Comment: I know, it's just to explain OP to understand what's happening with his code.

Answer (score 0):

Idk what you're trying to do here. but here's how you can do it.

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'Audi',
    type: 'sedan',
  },
  {
    name: 'BMW',
    type: 'sedan',
  },
  {
    name: 'Benz',
    type: 'suv',
  },
];
const array2 = [
  {
    year: '2020',
  },
  {
    year: '2021',
  },
];

const array3 = [];

array2.forEach((item, index) => {
  array1.forEach((item2) => {
    if (item2.type === 'sedan') {
      item.label = 'Sedan Car';
    }
  });
  array3.push(item);
});

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only the last value because you are re-using the same `customObject1` instance for every `array3` element. You would get better results by defining a new `customObject1` instance for each element:

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: "Audi",
    type: "sedan"
  },
  {
    name: "BMW",
    type: "sedan"
  },
  {
    name: "Benz",
    type: "suv"
  }
];
const array2 = [{
  year: "2020"
}, {
  year: "2021"
}];

let a = [];
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach((val1) => {
  array2.forEach((val2) => {
    if (val1.type === "sedan") {
      let customObject1 = {};
      customObject1["label"] = "Sedan Car";
      customObject1["year"] = val2.year;
      array3.push(customObject1);
      console.log(array3);
    }
  });
});
```

NOTE: This still does not produce the final results you seem to expect. That is because `array1` has two `sedan`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the same customObject reference is used during every iteration of the inner forEach loop. I would prefer a solution without using a variable at all by passing an object directly as a parameter in the push function.

```
let a = [];
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach((val1) => {
  array2.forEach((val2) => {
    if (val1.type === "sedan") {
      array3.push({ label: "Sedan Car", year: val2.year });
    }
  });
});
```

If you want to keep your variable were it is you could also make use of object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to create a copy

```
let a = [];
let customObject1 = {};
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach((val1) => {
  array2.forEach((val2) => {
    if (val1.type === "sedan") {
      customObject1["label"] = "Sedan Car";
      customObject1["year"] = val2.year;
      array3.push({...customObject1}) //destructuring the object;
      console.log(array3);
    }
  });
});
```